# Cordova failing to build on android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm attempting to build my android project via terminal. I have the /android-sdk/macosx in my downloads and I have the API 23 installed. I also have Google Play Services and Google Respository installed in Extras (within SDK Manager).

I'm receiving a build error when attempting to `cordova build android` as seen below. Am I missing something in my build setup? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running the SDK manager -> update for Android Support Repository -> Android Support Library